# Как отрендерить данные с помощью шаблонизатора в React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

С сервера приходят следующие данные:

html: `<div>{{name}}</div>`

и приходит json: `{"name": "Vasya"}`

**Вопрос:** как с помощью ReactJS распарсить эти данные и отобразить `<div>Vasya</div>`?

Делаю так:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function () {
         return {
            previewData: {}, // здесь приходит {"name":"Vasya"}
            previewHtml: {}  // здесь html "<div>{{name}}</div>"
    },
    getTemplateDataStore: function (event, previewData) {
        this.setState({
            previewData: previewData
        });
    },

    getTemplateHTMLStore: function (event, previewHtml) {
        this.setState({
            previewHtml: previewHtml
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return // ?????????? как отобразить <div>Vaysa</div>? 
    }
    },
});
```

Comment: По-хорошему, вам вообще не стоит использовать внешний шаблонизатор. Вместо этого, стоит передавать с сервера **только** данные, а всю шаблонизацию разбить по компонентам react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте шаблонизатор ( можно underscore, например )

```
render: function () {
    var template = _.template(this.state.previewHtml);
    return template(this.state.previewData);
}
```

[underscore #template](http://underscorejs.ru/#template)

Comment: а что на реакте нельзя это сделать?

Comment: @KristoferStrong, если не ошибаюсь, какой-то определенной ф-ции/метода нет. можно использовать [плагины](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/)

Comment: a lodach можно ли для этого использовать?

Comment: Можно – ф-я [`_.template()`](https://lodash.com/docs#template)

Comment: @KristoferStrong, самое главное, что ф-ция `render` должна возвращать строку, которая потом отрендериться. Чем вы ее возвращается, скорее всего не важно. Просто, нужно что бы ваша строка подходила под ваш шаблонизатор

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, если выбирать между lodach  и handlebars , то что вы бы посоветовали использовать ?

Comment: @KristoferStrong, не смогу помочь, так как не работал ни с одной из этих либ( Могу посоветовать [mustache.js](https://mustache.github.io/), как еще один вариант шаблонизатора

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, если у меня есть строка "<div>Vasya</div>" то как мне ее вывести с помощью реакта не в виде строки, а как html элемент див, внутри которого текст? Если я делаю render: return то мне выводится ,как строка

Comment: @KristoferStrong Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.